# How can I generalize this function for my __dict__ attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, id3

I have **dict** attribute to build a tree like structure.
I have this predict function which predicts accuracy of my decision tree based on attribute child relationship.

I want to generalize this function so I am able to predict my accuracy based on my **dict** attribute.

```
def __init__(self, _d):
         self.__dict__ = {a:DecisionNode(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else b for a, b in _d.items()}



def predicts(self, x):
            if self.children == {}: # reached leaf level
                return self.attribute
            value = x[self.attribute]
            subtree = self.children[value]
            return subtree.predicts(x)


for i in range(0,len(test)):
        if str(class_tree.predicts(test.loc[i])) == str(test.loc[1,target]):
            correct += 1
    print("\nThe accuracy is: ", correct/len(test))
```

This is what my **dict** attributes looks like -

```
class_tree.outlook.sunny.temperature.hot
Out[85]: 'no'
```

Comment: can you share the full code?

Comment: I wouldn't use `__dict__` directly.

Comment: @NimishBansal 
Let me tell that I used something like -
`tree = id3(train,target,attributes)
    class_tree = DecisionNode(tree)`
To create my __dict__ attributes

Comment: yes,if you share the complete code.we may find it easier to help :-)

Comment: @NimishBansal
https://expirebox.com/download/c8fe6eede5e227f20fa5051d454ce441.html

Comment: I think your code is not properly indented :-)